# Using grep to correct XML files

Tags: sed, xml-parsing, grep

I have a folder and sub folder that contains 2000 xml files. 
Need to process all the files with BizTalk systems. 
But some of the files has wrong tags
<strike>streetName Bombay Crescent  /addressRegion
/streetName</strike>.
I need to you grep to find and replace the worng tags only.
I.e with the for loop.. find any xml file with wrong tag and replace it.
Only  the tag "streetName" is affected. And only "addressRegion" is in the wrong place.
will like to do
    grep -Po where streetName and *** /addressRegion if the condition is true
replace /addressRegion with /streetName

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do.  Show us some examples, and show what you've tried already so we can help you.

Comment: I have some example but .. the website was not showing the code...<streetName> Bombay Crescent  </addressRegion>
.  the streetName is an xml element, which has addressRegion as a closing tag.. _The addressRegion should be change with </streetName> which is correct tag.. please note .. i cannot display the xml code correctly

Comment: the question and answer text accepts html formatting, which is why it swallows the xml tags.  Protect them with backticks `as if they were code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will look for a tag `<streetName>` that with a matching closing tag of `</addressRegion>`, and will change addressRegion to streetName.  It will replace all occurrences on the line.  The street name must not contain any `<` signs, that would break the matching.

```
sed -e 's:\(<streetName>[^<]*\)</addressRegion>:\1</streetName>:g'
```

The command reads its standard input and writes standard output.

Sed -i will do the replacement in-place in all its input files:

```
sed -i -e 's:\(<streetName>[^<]*\)</addressRegion>:\1</streetName>:g' folder/subfolder/*.xml
```

Comment: Hi Andras thanks.. Just a small question.. What does -e do in sed command?

Comment: -e executes that sed command.  s///g (or s:::g here, same thing) does a search-and-replace on every line of the input.  You can have multiple -e commands, they'll each run in sequence.  Another useful command is //d (delete lines matching pattern)

Comment: Hi Thanks .. one more last question. what if I decide to change the first tag.. in this case streetName to addressRegion. i.e the streetName is the wrong Tag. What do I have to modify in the code?

Comment: Change the `\( ... \)` captured text to save the tag body and the close-tag, and replace the open-tag:  `sed -i -e 's:<streetName>\([^<]*</addressRegion>\):<addressRegion>\1:g' folder/subfolder/*.xml`